# Returning and casting an array pointer (Error: invalid types ... for array subscript)

Tags: c++, arrays, sqlite, void-pointers

I found many threads about this but none of them seems to work. It's probably just a pointer mayem where I need to place the right number of stars at the right place but I can't figure it out.

I want to read a blob from an SQLITE database which was originally a 3 dimensional array. Sqlite returns a "const void*" and I need to convert this into an temporary table pointer so that I could do the transfer into the real table. But I get an:

```
error: invalid types ‘unsigned char[int]’ for array subscript
```

when trying to transfer the values from a table to another. Here is a sample of the code.

note: the functions prefixed with SQL... are personal wrappers for SQLITE and they should be working perfectly.

```
void Map::load ( void )
{
   int i, j, k;
   int errorsql;
   unsigned char *tmpmap; //[ Map_MAXDEPTH ] [ Map_MAXWIDTH ] [ Map_BYTE_WIDTH ];

   SQLactivate_errormsg();

   errorsql = SQLprepare ( "SELECT * FROM handmap;");

   if ( errorsql == SQLITE_OK)
   {
      errorsql = SQLstep ();

      if ( errorsql == SQLITE_ROW )
      {
         tmpmap = (unsigned char*) SQLcolumn_blob (1); // return the pointer to the blob

         for ( k = 0 ; k < Map_MAXDEPTH; k++ )
            for ( j = 0 ; j < Map_MAXWIDTH; j++)
               for ( i = 0; i < Map_BYTE_WIDTH; i++)
               {
                  p_map [ k ][ j ][ i ] = *tmpmap [ k ] [ j ] [ i ]; // try to copy from a table to another. Compiler fails here.
               }
      }
      else
         printf ("Map.load: Cannot step into the DB\n");

      SQLfinalize();
   }
   else
      printf ("Map.load: Cannot Prepare statement to save map into the DB\n");

   SQLdeactivate_errormsg();
}
```

The code is very simple, it tries to read column 1 from the first entry in the table (there is only 1 entry). The target array is p_map which is a 3D array of "unsigned char". But SQLcolumn_blob return a const void*.

So my idea was to create a pointer to an "unsigned char". Then convert the "const void*" as an "unsigned char*". And then use the unsigned char pointer as an array. But it seems that:

```
*tmpmap [ k ] [ j ] [ i ];
```

is illegal. I cannot use a pointer and reinterpret it as an array. So that is the though parts, because array are pointers but declared differently.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show where p_map is allocated, but you say it is a '3D' array of unsigned chars. If so it should be declared like this:

```
unsigned char p_map[Map_MAXDEPTH][Map_MAXWIDTH][Map_BYTE_WIDTH];
```

From some other bits of your code, it looks like it might be an array of `char *`, but there is certainly some confusion here:

```
     for ( k = 0 ; k < Map_MAXDEPTH; k++ )
        for ( j = 0 ; j < Map_MAXWIDTH; j++)
           for ( i = 0; i < Map_BYTE_WIDTH; i++)
           {
              p_map [ k ][ j ][ i ] = *tmpmap [ k ] [ j ] [ i ]; // try to copy from a table to another. Compiler fails here.
           }
```

I think you are saying `tmpmap` is a text blob and you want to copy it entirely into `p_map`. The easiest way of doing that would be simply:

```
memcpy (p_map, tmpmap, Map_MAXDEPTH * Map_MAXWIDTH * Map_BYTE_WIDTH * sizeof(char));
```

Note the multiplication by `sizeof(char)` is technically otiose as it is guaranteed to be 1.

If you are trying to do the copy with a loop and don't want to rely on the memory layout being identical, why not simply:

```
     int z = 0;
     for ( k = 0 ; k < Map_MAXDEPTH; k++ )
        for ( j = 0 ; j < Map_MAXWIDTH; j++)
           for ( i = 0; i < Map_BYTE_WIDTH; i++)
           {
              p_map [ k ][ j ][ i ] = tmpmap[z++];
           }
```

Comment: p_map is an object variable, but you have the definition right. The memcpy is interesting since I did the same with the text reading function. It's just that I was not sure how a 3D array aligned the data in real memory. I'll try both of them.

Comment: If `p_map` is an object with virtual functions, `memcpy`-ing over it is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Define tmpmap as

```
const unsigned char ( *tmpmap )[ Map_MAXWIDTH ] [ Map_BYTE_WIDTH ];
```

Also if the program is written in C++ then change this statement

```
tmpmap = SQLcolumn_blob (1);
```

to

```
tmpmap = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char ( *)[ Map_MAXWIDTH ] [ Map_BYTE_WIDTH ]>( SQLcolumn_blob (1) );
```

As for the error then it is obvious that you may not use tmpmap with three subscriptors because  tmpmap[i] has type unsigned char and is a scalar type.

Comment: Ah! I see. I'll try and see if it works. I use a mixture of C and C++ so I don't mind casting the old way.

Comment: I tried this method with the reinterpret cast. The compilation worked, but the results were not as desired. The map data was dispersed. I ended up using abligh's method

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, tmpmap acts as a single-dimensional array of char. In order for your code to work, you would have to convert k, j and i to a single array index. Something like:

int ind = i + (j * Map_BYTE_WIDTH) + (j * Map_BYTE_WIDTH * Map_MAXWIDTH);
p_map [ k ][ j ][ i ] = tmpmap[ind];

would I think do it. Alternatively you could define a type that was a suitably-sized 3D array and define tmpmap in terms of that type. Can't quite see ho wto do that right now...

Comment: The problem is that I don't have the control on what type of pointer SQLcolumn_blob returns. Still, I could create a structure containing a 3D array and the function should return a pointer to a structure.